# Facebook api, some posts don't have an url to link to

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting some data in json format and putting it into a custom facebook feed on my website.

But I noticed some urls are not working, because it doesn't get a link to the post, while others do have a link.

What is the reason for that?

Example (I edited the real data):

```
{
  "full_picture": "facebook.com/image.jpg",
  "story": "Lorem ipsum added 5 new photos.",
  "link": "facebook.com/loremipsum",
  "updated_time": "2016-04-21T08:11:56+0000",
  "id": "267007566742236_9112352353963611923"
},

{
  "message": "lorem ipsum",
  "updated_time": "2016-05-26T18:58:50+0000",
  "id": "267007566742236_90323523789831074"
},
```

Like you can see, one has a link, but the other doesn't. If I go to the facebook page and click on the date of the post, it opens in a new tab, so there should be an accesible url.

I get everything with file_get_contents:

```
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/267032532566742236/feed?fields=full_picture%2Cmessage%2Cstory%2Clink%2Cupdated_time&access_token=23532523523523%dsgsdg322352352235");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link` property of post objects is for the URL that might have been *attached* to the post.

What you want, is the `permalink_url` field.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it not in the Facebook documentation? I thought these were all the possible parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: If something is missing from the docs, feel free to file a documentation bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs From my experience, the FB guys are thankful whenever you help them improve stuff.